# ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) missing FROM-clause entry for table "artist" LINE 1: SELECT year, artist.inverted, track FROM billboard

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

So I'm trying to query a PostgreSQL database with a table containing billboard top 200 data. One of the columns is called 'artist.inverted' and when I try to select that column, I get the error message in the title.

`ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) missing FROM-clause entry for table "artist" LINE 1: SELECT year, artist.inverted, track FROM billboard`

It must be because the column contains a . in it. Is there anyway to fix this without renaming the column? And if I have to rename the column, will I be able to do so without running into a similar error due to the period in the name?

Comment: Put the name in double quotes: `"artist.inverted"`.

Comment: How's this related to SQLAlchemy btw? In other words, show your code. Debugging questions require a [mcve].